# Angular - Injecting component instance into the view of another component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm creating tabs control using Angular. The result should look like this:

```
<tabs>
   <tab header="tab 1">
     hello
   </tab>
   <tab header="tab 2">
     world
   </tab>
</tabs>
```

Now, the *tab* component looks like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'tab',
    template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class TabComponent {
    @Input() header: string;
}
```

And the *tabs* component looks like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'tabs',
    template: `
       <div class="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let tab of tabs">
                    <a (click)="selectTab(tab)">
                        {{tab.header}}
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    `,
})
export class TabsComponent {
    @ContentChildren(TabComponent) tabs;

    selectTab(tab: TabComponent) {

    }
 }
```

Now, when the selectTab() method is called, I want the content of the pressed tab ("hello" or "world") to be rendered at the bottom of the template.

Basically there needs to be some kind of a tab placeholder in the *TabsComponent*, and it needs to be bonded to the currently selected *TabComponent*.

Anyway, I can't get it to work. I've tried using *ng-template* and *createEmbeddedView*, but I don't understand how to get the TemplateRef from the component, and I'm not completely sure that's the right way to go.

Thanks ahead!

Comment: why you don't have `ng-content` in the `TabsComponent` template?

Comment: Because then all the tabs will appear in there, and I only want the *selected* tab to appear.

Comment: if you don't use it Angular ignores everything inside `<tabs>content ignored</tabs>` tag.

Comment: That's not accurate, because I'm using the ContentChildren decorator. It retrieves all the *TabComponent*s inside the tabs, and then used by the *TabsComponnet* to generate tab headers. I want to display the relevant *TabComponent* when a user press on a tab header.

Comment: right, you can access them through `ContentChildren`. what exactly do you need from `tabcompoennt` content? right now it's just text there, do you need that text? can you add a template reference like this `<tab><span #t> hello</span></tab>`

Comment: I want whatever inside `<tab>` to be presented inside *TabsComponent* after a tab header as been pressed...

Comment: there's no way to get contents of the component apart from querying it with `@ViewChildren` or `@ContenChildren`, but to do so the content has to be either components/directives or with template references

Comment: The problem is that I want all the children, and I want to add them to the DOM when the tab header is pressed. How can I achieve that? I think *viewcontainerref* has something to do with that... or maybe *TemplateRef*..

Comment: so it's acceptable to wrap `tab` content into `ng-template` like this `<tab><ng-template>hello</ng-template></tab>`?

Comment: I don't think it's the best solution... and even if I'll do it, what's next?

Comment: You don't understand how Angular manipulates the DOM, read [Exploring Angular DOM manipulation techniques using ViewContainerRef](https://hackernoon.com/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I solved it, but I'm not sure this is the right solution.
I repeat my needs:
I want to make a fully-functioning tab-set component, that consists of tab headers and the currently selected tab.

Example:
https://s3.envato.com/files/169665336/Thetabs%20-%20Responsive%20HTML5%20&%20CSS3%20Tabs%202016-01-29%2005-57-05.png

So here's my solution. Please feel free to suggest a better one, as I'm not completely sure this is the example of a tab-set component:

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'tab',
})
export class TabDirective {
    private static seed = 0;

    readonly id: number;

    @Input() header: string;

    @HostBinding('hidden') isHidden: boolean;

    private isActive: boolean;
    @HostBinding('class.active') set active(value: boolean) {
        this.isActive = value;
        this.isHidden = !this.isActive;
    }

    get active(): boolean {
        return this.isActive;
    }

    constructor() {
        this.id = TabDirective.seed++;
        this.active = false;
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'bu-tabs',
    template: `
       <div class="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let tab of tabs" [class.is-active]="tab.active">
                    <a (click)="selectTab(tab)">
                        <span>{{tab.header}}</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <ng-content></ng-content>
    `,
})
export class TabsComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ContentChildren(TabDirective) tabs: QueryList<TabDirective>;

    @Output() select = new EventEmitter<TabDirective>();

    private selectedTab: TabDirective;

    selectTab(tab: TabDirective) {
        this.tabs.forEach((t: TabDirective) => t.active = (t.id === tab.id));
        this.selectedTab = tab;
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        if (this.tabs && this.tabs.length > 0) {
            this.tabs.first.active = true;
        }
    }
}

@Component({
    template: `
        <tabs>
            <bu-tab header="hello">
                Hello!!
            </bu-tab>
            <bu-tab header="world">
                World!!
            </bu-tab>
        </tabs>
  `,
})
export class App { }
```

Comment: Hi Eliran, Can you please post a full code sample ?